# Ubuntu 23.10 not detecting second monitor

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, 23.10

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) as a my main OS. I am facing issue in dual screen monitor sharing, I cannot see "join" and "mirror"  Options under "Dispay Setting"
While I have watched video of same OS, in that video, there was option to mirror screen

I am using Acer Travelmate Laptop with Integrated Intel Graphics. Please find below info :

```
root@nirmal:/home/nirmal# inxi -SGayz
System:
Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A clocksource: tsc
available: acpi_pm parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic
root=UUID=aef22b3f-63c7-42dd-9d7b-daa73d2ebfca ro quiet splash
vt.handoff=7
Desktop: GNOME v: 45.1 tk: GTK v: 3.24.38 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3
v: 45.beta Distro: Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI
driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-9 process: Intel 14n built: 2015-16 ports:
active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:1916
class-ID: 0300
Device-2: Quanta HD WebCam driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 1-7:6 chip-ID: 0408:a030
class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
Display: server: X.Org v: 1.23.2 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.0
compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting
dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1366x768 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 361x203mm (14.21x7.99")
s-diag: 414mm (16.31")
Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: ChiMei InnoLux 0x14c3 built: 2015 res: 1366x768
hz: 60 dpi: 112 gamma: 1.2 size: 310x170mm (12.2x6.69") diag: 354mm (13.9")
ratio: 16:9 modes: 1366x768
API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1 renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics
520 (SKL GT2) direct-render: Yes
```

Please, anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks